# Extended command button order

Tags: forms, buttons, human-interface-guideline, best-practice

As far as I can tell from looking at a large number of Windows forms and dialogues, Microsoft uses the following pattern to dictate the order that their buttons appear:

```
[Val- / Prev] [Val+ / Next] [Do] [Don't Do / Reset] [Cancel / Close] [Pseudo-Do] [Info / Help]
```

The trouble is that I have no way of confirming if this is the case. Does anyone know where I might find an official confirmation of this pattern or where I might find the same information for other platforms/applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [Windows Dev Center Guidlines entry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is very lengthy, but makes many references to command buttons you've listed and their ideal order.

It doesn't specifically mention the buttons you've listed, but this [MSDN User Interface Principles guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff728831%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#intuitiveness) outlines Microsoft's standard for button intuitiveness.